# How do I get a better time complexity Big O in exercise about page sequences in java

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

The problem is:

Entries are written in chronological order to a file with one entry per line. The format of each entry is:

[timestamp][space][user-id][space][page-type-id]\n

Your task is to determine the 10 most common three page sequences across all users from a set of logs.

For example, here is an example log:

```
1248977297 BBBB Search
1248977302 AAAA Browse
1248977308 BBBB Search
1248977310 AAAA Browse
1248977317 BBBB Search
1248977325 AAAA Search
1248977332 AAAA Search
1248977332 BBBB Search
1248977339 BBBB Checkout
1248977348 AAAA Search
1248977352 BBBB Browse
1248977367 AAAA Search



The first three-page sequence made by user AAAA is “Browse->Browse->Search”
The second three-page-sequence made by user AAAA is “Browse->Search->Search” 
The third three-page-sequence made by user AAAA is “Search->Search->Search”
The fourth three-page-sequence made by user AAAA is “Search->Search->Search”
```

The output of the program given the example data should be:

```
Search -> Search -> Search = 4
Browse -> Browse -> Search = 1
Search -> Search -> Checkout = 1
Browse -> Search -> Search = 1
Search -> Checkout -> Browse = 1
```

The output must contain the top 10 three-page sequences (in order) and the number of occurrences for each one.

**The best algorithm that comes to my mind is O(n^2), but I find answers that says It can be done in O(N+ N*lg(N)), how can I archive that complexity?, the say that listing in O(N) and sort in O(N lg(N))**

```
/* Solution
 * Runtime complexity: O(n^2).
 * Spatial complexity: O(n).
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        /*
         * Reads the input from a txt file.
         */
        String file = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\txt\\files";
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file + ".txt"));
        String line = "";

        /*
         * @map data structure to store all the users with their page ids.
         */
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        /*
         *Read the txt or log file and store in the @map the user<Integer> and in a list<String> all the page sequences that he visited.
         */
        while ((line = f.readLine()) != null && line.trim().length() != 0) {
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
                String timeStamp = tokens.nextToken();
                int userId = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
                String pageType = tokens.nextToken();

                List<String> values = map.get(userId);
                if (values == null) {
                    values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    map.put(userId, values);
                }
                values.add(pageType);
            }
        }
        /*
         * Create the sequences by user.
         */
        List<String> listSequences = generateSequencesByUser(map);

        /*
         * Count the frequency of each sequence.
         */
        Map<String, Integer> mapFrequency = countFrequencySequences(listSequences);

        /*
         * Sort the map by values.
         */
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = Solution.sortByValue(mapFrequency);

        /*
         * Print the Top 10 of sequences.
         */
        printTop10(sortedMap);
    }
    /*
     * Method to create sequences by user.
     */
    public static List<String> generateSequencesByUser(Map<Integer, List<String>> map) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            int key = entry.getKey();
            for (int i = 2; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                String seq = entry.getValue().get(i - 2) + "->" + entry.getValue().get(i - 1) + "->" + entry.getValue().get(i);
                list.add(seq);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    /*
     * Method the frequency of each sequence and stored in a map.
     */
    public static Map<String, Integer> countFrequencySequences(List<String> listSequences) {
        Map<String, Integer> mapFrequency = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String temp : listSequences) {
            Integer counter = mapFrequency.get(temp);
            if (counter == null) {
                counter = 1;
                mapFrequency.put(temp, counter);
            } else {
                mapFrequency.put(temp, counter + 1);
            }
        }
        return mapFrequency;
    }

    /*
     * Method to print the top 10 of sequences.
     */
    public static void printTop10(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            count++;
            if (count > 10) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Order the map by values.
     */
    public static Map<String, Integer> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
            }
        });

        Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the task in O(N LogN) or better by splitting the problem into three simpler tasks:

1. Order the list by timestamp,
2. Making counts for each three-page sequence, and
3. Picking top ten items by count.

The first task is a standard sorting. Let's assume that it's O(N LogN) for now<sup>*</sup>.

The second task is easily accomplished with a pair of hash maps:

- For each user, keep a three-element list of his last three pages in the first hash map. Each time a new action by the user is discovered, shift the pages in the list by one.
- If the list from the step above has three entries, make a three-part key for them, and increment its count in the second hash map.

Each step above is an O(1) operation per log entry, so the timing for this task is O(N)

The third task of selecting the top ten entries by count can be done by retrieving key-count pairs, and sorting them by count. In the worst case when all page transitions are unique you would end up with 3N entries to sort, so this task is again an O(N LogN) <sup>*</sup>.

Once you know the algorithm, the implementation should be straightforward, because Java supplies all building blocks for implementing each task of the algorithm.

<sup>*</sup> You can reduce the timing to O(N) by making two observations:

- The first task uses ten-digit numbers for timestamps, so you can employ a non-comparative linear-time algorithm, such as [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), to achieve linear timing, and
- Picking top ten items can be achieved through a linear-time s[election algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

This implementation would require considerably more work, though, because Java does not supply ready-made "building blocks" for it.

Comment: thanks for answering I have a question if I undertood well you say that I need two hashmap Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(); this for the user, and Map<String, Integer > map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); for the sequence and count, where sequence is the key and value is the count, how do you get a complexity of  O(N LogN) in a hashmap if you order by value? Collections.sort o arrays.sort?

Comment: @rommel Actually, the first hash map would be `String` to `String[]` array, and the second would be `String` to `Integer`. Take a look at the demo ([here](http://ideone.com/KRZ0n1)) that does the counting, without the final sorting. The middle step is O(N), it's the first and the last ones that are O(N LogN), because they use sorting.

Comment: so if I have 100, 000 or more entries I have to use Arrays.sort and a comparator right?

Comment: @rommel What does a comparator have to do with the number of entries in an array?

Comment: nothing, I was trying to say if the amount of entries increases, the best is using a sort and a comparator, so I can order by values that is what I found on internet

Comment: @rommel You can do it with any number of entries, really - in fact, you would need to do a custom sort in order to complete the program from my demo. What I meant in the footnote is that you could use advanced algorithms to bring down the asymptotic complexity of your code by using sorting techniques that do not rely on comparisons (and hence cannot be brought into the framework of Java's collection sorting algorithm, which is based on comparisons).